# Outputting GLfloat value gives correct value, but storing it in another variable and outputting that variable, gives the wrong value

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a project using freeglut and glew, although I think that's irrelevant to my problem. These first line outputs the values that I expect it to. (-1, -1). Note: mikesVertices[0].x and mikesVertices[0].y are of the type GLfloat.

```
std::cout << "(" << mikesVertices[0].x << ", " << mikesVertices[0].y << ")" << endl;
```

However, these two lines ( which come immediately after..

```
GLfloat x = mikesVertices[0].x;
std::cout << "x: " << x << endl;
```

outputs an incorrect value for x. (1.92749e-039)

The reason I am trying to do this is because I want to pass the values to a function, but the function is also getting the wrong values. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: mikesVertices is a pointer to a vec2 object ( written by Angel, I've shown parts out of it which I think seemed necessary )

```
struct vec2 {

GLfloat  x;
GLfloat  y;

//
//  --- Constructors and Destructors ---
//

vec2( GLfloat s = GLfloat(0.0) ) :
x(s), y(s) {}

vec2( GLfloat x, GLfloat y ) :
x(x), y(y) {}

vec2( const vec2& v )
{ x = v.x;  y = v.y;  }

//
//  --- Insertion and Extraction Operators ---
//

friend std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const vec2& v ) {
return os << "( " << v.x << ", " << v.y <<  " )";
}

friend std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& is, vec2& v )
{ return is >> v.x >> v.y ; }

//
//  --- Conversion Operators ---
//

operator const GLfloat* () const
{ return static_cast<const GLfloat*>( &x ); }

operator GLfloat* ()
{ return static_cast<GLfloat*>( &x ); }
```

Comment: Could we see the data structure of `mikesVertices`, along with the declaration of the variable?

Comment: Please post a ["Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"](http://sscce.org/). Also, `GLfloat` is almost certainly a typedef of `float`, so this really has nothing to do with OpenGL.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Could you provide compiler and options?

Comment: First guess: "mikesVertices" has been deallocated, and it just happens to still have the correct values until after that complicated and uses-a-bit-of-stack-and-heap std::cout stuff is called

Comment: @ChristianStieber seems to be right, I'll just store the variable before I use it for a temporary fix. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Using printf instead of cout might also show what's really going on.. =)